# Migrating from M1 to M2: need to / want to rename multiple attributes

Tags: attributes, url-rewrite

in our mission to migrate from M1 to M2 we need / want to rename attributes that we have named say 7 years ago.

So product attribute 'manufacturer' would become 'brand'
and product attribute 'product_color' would become 'color'

We have tried looking at nginx rewrite. Only it does not handly query params editing very well and even less changing multiple! parameters.

SO I was thinking: as a workaround: could we add some kind of lookup / araay of old and new parameters somwhere that if/when we query in our layered bavigation for

manufacturer=51 or brand=51 => that the result would be the same? Or that the old attribute would be replace with a 301 to the new attribute?

and this would work with multiple attributes too?

manufacturer=51&product_color=1 becomes brand=51&color=1

Help appreciated ;)